# Singleton Android Not Able To Access Data

Tags: java, android, multithreading, singleton

I am trying to take data from one class, put it in a singleton, and then proceed to access that data in another class.

Here is my singleton:

```
public class DataTransferrer {
    private static DataTransferrer instance = null;

    private ArrayList<Transients> transientList;

    private DataTransferrer(){
        transientList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static synchronized DataTransferrer getInstance(){
        if(instance == null) {instance = new DataTransferrer();}
        return instance;
    }

    public ArrayList<Transients> getTransients(){return this.transientList;}

    public void setTransients(ArrayList<Transients> t){transientList = t;}

    public void printAll(){
        for(Transients t : transientList){
            Log.d("DEBUG DA",t.getDa().toString());
        }
    }

    }
```

Here is my method that adds data to an `arrayList` which is then set to the `arrayList` within the singleton to then be used elsewhere:

```
public class JSONParser {

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://pi.cs.oswego.edu/~lpatmore/getAllTransients.php";

    ArrayList<Transients> transientList;

    private Transients t;

    public JSONParser(){
        transientList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void execute(){
        new GetTransients().execute();
    }
    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetTransients extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.d(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                    Log.d(TAG, "NOT NULL DEBUG");
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray transients = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

                    // looping through All Transients
                    for (int i = 0; i < transients.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = transients.getJSONObject(i);

                        String author = c.getString("author");
                        String transientId = c.getString("transientId");
                        String dateAlerted = c.getString("dateAlerted");
                        String datePublished = c.getString("datePublished");
                        float right_asencsion = (float) c.getDouble("right_asencsion");
                        float declination = (float) c.getDouble("declination");

                        t = new Transients(author, transientId, dateAlerted, datePublished, right_asencsion, declination);

                        // adding trans to trans list
                        transientList.add(t);
                    }
                    DataTransferrer.getInstance().setTransients(transientList);
                    DataTransferrer.getInstance().printAll();
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

And I try to access it in another class like:

```
 for(int i = 0; i <      DataTransferrer.getInstance().getTransients().size(); i++){
        System.out.println("DEBUG ADDED TRANSIENT");
        Float ra = DataTransferrer.getInstance().getTransients().get(i).getR();
        Float dec = DataTransferrer.getInstance().getTransients().get(i).getD();
        transients.add(new Transient("Transient", names[i], GeocentricCoordinates.getInstance(ra, dec)));
    }
```

Whenever I debug it checking to see in the other class, I am trying to access the `arraylist`, but in the other class it's like there was never an array list added to `getTransients()` method.

I tested this exact setup in Eclipse and it works perfectly but not in Android Studio.

Comment: Can you add the whole method where you have got your `for` loop ?

Comment: where did you create `transientList` in that method ?

Comment: @javaguy I added the rest of the code to the `for` loop method, I actually added the whole class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tested this exact setup in Eclipse and it works perfectly but not in
>   Android Studio.

Basically, **you have got multithreading issue** i.e., your `DataTransferrer` class is NOT threadsafe which is causing the issue i.e., there is a race condition between multiple threads and your singleton `instance` is NOT actually singleton (multiple objects are being created for `DataTransferrer` class).

So when you calling `setTransients()` from one thread, it is actually storing the `Transients` in one `instance` of `DataTransferrer` and then when you are trying retrieve the `Transients` from a different thread it is using different `instance` (object) of `DataTransferrer`.

You can create threadsafe singleton instance for your `DataTransferrer` class as shown below:

```
public class DataTransferrer {

        private static final DataTransferrer instance = new DataTransferrer();

        private ArrayList<Transients> transientList = new ArrayList<>();

        //private constructor, so instantiation NOT allowed
        private DataTransferrer() {}

        public static synchronized DataTransferrer getInstance(){
          return instance;
        }

       public ArrayList<Transients> getTransients(){
           return this.transientList;
       }

        public void setTransients(ArrayList<Transients> t){
            transientList = t;
        }

        public void printAll(){
            for(Transients t : transientList){
                Log.d("DEBUG DA",t.getDa().toString());
            }
        }
 }
```

Also, note that in the above code, **the `instance` will be created eagerly** during the startup (initializing) time and when you call `setTransients` and `getTransients` that same `instance` (singleton) will be used. Instead of eager creation, if you need to create the `instance` lazily, you can look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/singleton-1577166.html).